# Correlation between discrete and categorical variables?

Tags: correlation, anova, categorical-data

I am attempting to determine how to test the relationship between a discrete variable (the length of a string of text, my IV) and a categorical variable (binary, a yes or no outcome, my DV) but I'm having trouble figuring out the best methodology. Would it be incorrect to use a one-way ANOVA or is that a valid method?

I had performed an ANOVA and gotten good results (p-value < 0.05 indicating a relationship) but upon further research I'm less confident that the one-way ANOVA has given me good or valid results.

Comment: There is no correlation when categorical variables are involved, so that goes out the window. What is your research question?

Comment: How is "length of string" a discrete variable? If your DV is binary, then the usual method would be logistic regression.

Comment: What’s wrong with the usual Pearson correlation?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "testing the relationship", trying to find out if length of string has an influence at all, or something more detailed?

Comment: @user2974951 research question is what is the strength of the relationship between these two variables.

Comment: @PeterFlom wouldn't length of a string be discrete bc you can't have 2.5 words or 2.25 words but rather only 2 words or 3 words in a string?

Comment: @Dave won't Pearson correlation only work between on non-categorical vairables?

Comment: @Ute exactly, just to find out if the length of the string has an influence on the outcome (i.e. if a user writes a longer string of text, are they more or less likely to indicate a satisfied answer vs a not satisfied)

Comment: @proofs_challenged Oops, my bad. I was thing string like yarn.

Comment: How big is your sample size, and what is the range of string lengths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have given us very little information to build on, so please edit your question so we can know more (sample size? Showing us an excerpt of data, or a link? Plots? ...) but in the meantime ...

For a binary dependent variable and a numerical covariate, logistic regression is my starting point. Search this site ... and see also [Correlations with unordered categorical variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/108007/correlations-with-unordered-categorical-variables),  [Correlations between continuous and categorical (nominal) variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/102778/correlations-between-continuous-and-categorical-nominal-variables),  [Correlation between dichotomous and continuous variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25229/correlation-between-dichotomous-and-continuous-variable),